# Silverlight Grid Highlight row and column

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a grid which is dynamically added to the Layout-root which could have X amount of rows and X amount of columns. What I am wanting to do is when the client hovers over a cell in the grid the X and Y axis is highlighted.

Example Shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Border control to each cell and change thickness for border when enters. When mouse leaves you can set thickness to 0.